# how to prevent aws-sdk from setting bucket as subdomain for an ip address as endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

i get an object storage service from a company and they use aws s3 structure.so you can use libraries designed for aws s3 to connect to there storage(libraries like boto3 for python and aws-sdk for javascript).i use aws-sdk.

i need to use an ip address to access the storage so i need to set endpoint to their ip address, and it works fine. problem is that this company file storage system is a bit different than aws. while aws use bucket name as a subdomain, this company use bucket name in the path of the file.

aws: bucket.amazon.com
their: <-ipaddress->/public/bucket/...

and its just fine when using boto3, but when i use aws-sdk and when i set bucket in params, aws-sdk set bucket as subdomin of ip address and it dont work any more.

since it work fine when using boto3, i thought it must work with aws-sdk as well. so im looking for a way  to prevent aws-sdk to set bucket as subdomain and use it in a different way.

```
    const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
    const ep = new AWS.Endpoint("http://<ip address>");
    global.s3 = new AWS.S3({
      apiVersion: "2006-03-01",
      endpoint: ep,
    }); 
   

    const params = {
          Bucket: `${process.env.AWS_BUCKET}`,
          Prefix: `${_path}`,
        };

    const result = await s3.listObjects(params).promise();
```

result of the above code is this error:
`Inaccessible host: <bucket>.<ip address>. This service may not be available in the us-east-1' region.'`

whick is currect because this address does not exists. but how can i fix this.

it works fine when im getting bucket list and bucket is not set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

after three days looking for the answer, finally find the solution.
aws s3 has two way of handling bucket.

1. : use it in subdomain to connect to it
2. : use it in the path of your object

in my case i should use the second way and the way to do it is to config aws-sdk and set `s3ForcePathStyle` to true. like this: `AWS.config.s3ForcePathStyle = true;`

and problem solved.

Comment: As I understand this path style API is deprecated and removed?  

https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/amazon-to-disable-s3-path-style-access-used-to-bypass-censorship/

Comment: You still can use it for S3 service providers other than AWS like Flexify.io so you wont have the "Inaccessible host: <bucket>.<ip address>" stated problem.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer of @halo, I was able to figure out how to do this with the S3 Client to e.g connect to a s3 compatible storage like OBS (open telekom cloud, Huawai cloud etc.) or to connect to e.g minio running locally.

```
import { S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
new S3Client({
    forcePathStyle: true, // needed for localstack
    endpoint: 'localhost:9000', //when using minio
    credentials: {
        secretAccessKey: 'hello',
        accessKeyId: 'supersecret',
    },
}),
```